# Unable to login to my account using terminal

Tags: 12.04, kernel, bashrc

I was trying to add some lines to the end of `.bashrc` file by following instructions to install `rvm` on Ubuntu 12.04 , now when i am putting in password after doing a `sudo su` the terminal freezes .

Following are the [contents](http://pastebin.com/C0iqJjPS) of `.bashrc`

Can someone please guide me what should i do to bring things back to the old working self , any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Thanks to the guys at freenode , my problem was solved using sudo -i command

Comment: You should answer your own question, so that others having the same problem can know how you worked it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other alternatives as suggested to `sudo su` command are `sudo -i` and `sudo -H`.

I'm still wondering what caused the `sudo su` command to stop working.

Comment: sudo HS? are you sure? maybe it was sudo sh. could you please confirm the exact command

Comment: i just tried the sudo -i command and it worked for me , i was suggested the same command sudo HS (haven't tried it though)